# how to convert string to Dictionary by first word is value and 3 more words is keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

i want convert string to dictionary for example
my string is `"Man I Je Ich"`
so dictionary result is

```
{
'I' : 'Man',
'Je': 'Man',
'Ich': 'Man' 
}
```

first word is value and 3 more words is keys

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works file:

```
string = "Man I Je Ich"
keys = string.split()
data = {key: keys[0] for key in keys[1:]}
```

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You could get the first word and the rest in separate variables then use a `dict` comprehension to create the `dict`:

```
s = "Man I Je Ich"
val, *keys = s.split()
data = {k: val for k in keys}
```

---

```
{'I': 'Man', 'Je': 'Man', 'Ich': 'Man'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this dud..

```
string = "Man I Je Ich"
#split string to words
words = string.split()
#get first word as key
key = words[0]
#remove the key from words
del words[0]
#create your dictionary
dictionary = {}
for word in words:
  dictionary[word] = key
print(dictionary)
```